# How to change deployment target from iOS 5.1 to 4.2 in Xcode 4.4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.4

I am trying to change the deployment target from 5.1 to 4.2 in Xcode 4.4 and it's not working

- I downloaded debugging support for 4.1-4.2
- I set Architecture to armv6 armv7
- I set in plist armv6 armv7
- I don't use storyboards

Comment: What isn't working?  Does it not compile?  Does it decide it doesn't want to downgrade?  Does it not run in 4.2?

Comment: Sorry. When i compile i get warning: `Xcode cannot run using the selected device (iphone 3g 4.2.1). Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device`

Comment: i change architecture to armv7 and 6, and i've got error: `No such file or directory (/Users/tomkowz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ewqeubdkdxvizebssqvbjuojdwqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/name.app/name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/11889190). XCode 4.4 doesn't let you target armv6 architecture. You'll have to downgrade to Xcode 4.3.3 to do this (learned it the hard way :-/). You'll have to download 4.3.3 from the Apple dev website.

Also, make sure not to run both 4.4 and 4.3.3 at once. My mac was semi frozen for an hour until I managed to force kill these two processes.

Update: This bug has been fixed in the newer versions of the XCode.

Comment: ehhh.. thank you for answer. and it's no more way for make application  for 4.2?

Comment: I dont think so (unless apple release an update for XCode that fixes this issue)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still affected by this issue, it appears to have been fixed.  In Xcode 4.4.1 I do not have this problem.  (Specifically, when I set architecture to armv6 armv7, I am able to build for an iPhone 3G running 4.2 - I have not tried other combinations.)

Comment: No: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463195/xcode-4-5-and-ios-4-2-1-incompatibility