# After installing XCode 4.5, how can I compile for prior to iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I upgraded to Xcode 4.5 and found out that I cannot support/compile for devices prior to 4.3. 
I could not use my old version of XCode 4.2 because it does not start anymore after upgrading to Mountain Lion. 
I had testing devices with iOS 4.xx. I want to install apps to those devices for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Xcode 4.4.1 supports devices before iOS 4.3 and it also works on Mountain Lion. So, I downloaded Xcode 4.4.1

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746735/how-to-change-deployment-target-from-ios-5-1-to-4-2-in-xcode-4-4) helped me figure out this.

p.s: I could not upgrade my testing devices to iOS 4.3 even though I downloaded the framework and tried to install it via iTunes.